# how much free memory left in ios device means low memory?

Tags: ios, memory

do anybody knows how much free memory left in ios device means low memory? 30M or 50M. Sometimes I encounter some crashes, such as mmap fail with only 50M free memory or less left, can I get the conclusion that it is low memory issue!

Comment: Probably depends on the device

Comment: how about the iphone 6?